# pgAdminIII Bug on Query Tool

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Hi I have the following bug on pgAdminIII:

[image]

If I open the SQL Query tool page none of the buttons are visible and only if I go over the upper line some of them become visible. But I can't write or execute any query.
I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it many times also with other version but the same thing happens all the time. 
Did anyone experience the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a [bug](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAG7mmoyQpZ3hFUnjG3Oo82ZXshuc_ifpH2NLpaXTEMx2WFnTPQ@mail.gmail.com). Try the `View -> 'Default View'` in the Query window as an alternative way. Also update pgadmin and check.